# \begin{document} breaks redefinition of \Re

Tags: macros, unicode-math

To replace the Gothic type real-part operator by a plain 'Re', the following works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
[...]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math} % must come after ams and symbols
[...]
\begin{document}
\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}
```

However, if I interchange the last two lines, my redefinition of `\Re` is ineffectual. What is happening? How can `\begin{document}` overwrite a macro redefinition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of commands in `unicode-math` are contained in `\AtBeginDocument` so are first run around the point when the processing gets to the `\begin{document}` command.  You can use the same trick yourself to override a definition:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}}
\begin{document}

\( \Re z \)
\end{document}
```

Similar commands such as `\AtEndOfPackage` are also defined in core LaTeX.  Additional commands including `\AtBeginEnvironment` are in the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Do you possibly know _why_ `unicode-math` postpones some definitions to `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @JoachimWuttke A lot of stuff has to be delayed until other package loading is done: there are complex interactions to worry about.

Comment: @JosephWright: Or too complex to worry about in advance - since there is no systematic way to prevent package interferences, we only can debug them ex post ... ?

Comment: @JoachimWuttke In the current case it's not interference as such but simpe logic. If you load another font package after `unicode-math` it may alter `\Re` in a way that's unexpected, so the best approach is to leave things until all package loading is done.

Comment: @JosephWright But, contrariwise, if I'm using another font package that alters `\Re` then it's `unicode-math` that's operating in an unexpected way.